# My NuGet package installed successfully, but it did not install the library

Tags: nuget, .net-framework-version

First time trying to release into NuGet. This is what I did:

- I created a .NET Framework class library **FrontEdge.dll**.
- I used .NET Reactor to obfuscate it.
- I created a **FrontEdge.nuspec** file and a **License.txt**.
- I zipped these three files and renamed the zip file to "**FrontEdge.nupkg**".
- I uploaded it to NuGet.

The content of the specs were properly displayed. When I used the "Open in NuGet Package Explorer" feature on NuGet website to display the content of this package, I can see **FrontEdge.dll** and  **License.txt**.

I then created a test project and added reference to this class library using NuGet. Everything went through without any error, it prompted the license and I pressed "Accept", but the project's **References** showed that all the dependencies had been installed, but **FrontEdge.dll** was not.

I don't know what I did wrong. Please help!

Comment: I would use 'nuget pack your.nuspec' to generate the .nupkg instead of creating it yourself - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/cli-reference/cli-ref-pack. Also posting the .nuspec file may help diagnose the problem. I would guess that the dll is not in a lib subdirectory in the .nupkg file.

Comment: Thank you so much Matt! I put the DLL in a "lib" folder, and now it is working. Thank you!